# Hide overflow without clearing floated element

Tags: html, css, overflow

I have an image floated to the left of a banner area which is taller than I want the banner to be, this is to leave room for the text to grow without the image cutting off.

[image: before overflow: hidden is applied]

When I apply `overflow: hidden` to `.banner` the banner clears the image instead of cutting it off.

[image: after overflow: hidden is applied]

I understand *why* this happens but I have been trying to figure out a way to get the desired effect to no avail. See the desired effect below.

[image: the desired effect]

I have tried various things like putting the image with a div and applying `overflow: hidden` to that but I can't seem to get it to work.

I'm sure that the answer is staring me right in the face but I'm just not seeing it.

I have uploaded my code to a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjd37jtL/) for you (with a much smaller image so you can see the effect in the result window)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here i updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mjd37jtL/1/) so you can see the result.
You have to take the image out of the Textflow with `position: absolute;`.
With this, the image gets cut off, if the text is not high enough to show it all.

Comment: I did try something like this however I am concerned that in doing this I will need to use JavaScript to calculate the padding to the left of the caption when going responsive. I will keep this in mind, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this, if you know the width of the image: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/EcJAK

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.banner {
    margin-top: 35px;
    background: #f00;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.banner img {
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}

.caption {
    margin-left: 230px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="banner">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/220x300" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="caption">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam asperiores dicta est, iure libero molestias pariatur. Aperiam aut autem consequatur, deleniti et eum minus nihil perspiciatis provident qui repellendus veniam voluptatem. Aliquid assumenda atque consequatur cumque nesciunt sequi. Adipisci autem cumque iste itaque laudantium necessitatibus optio possimus quam sint vero!</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options you could go for:

1 . Apply the float to the image's DIV instead the image itself, and limit the DIV's height to the wanted minimum height.

Example:

```
    .image{ float:left; height:1px; }
```

JSfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/z3zfx7uv/

2 . Get rid of the image and it's DIV altogether and use background-image instead, with appropriate padding-left.

Example:

```
    .banner {
        margin-top: 35px;
        background: #f00 url(http://placehold.it/220x300) top left no-repeat;
        overflow: hidden;
        padding-left:220px;
    }
```

JSfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/b6zzbowh/